# Plotting edge modes for a tight binding Hamiltonian with superconducting pairing

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators

I would like to obtain a plot such as the one in the first picture for the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian reported in the second picture. The problem here is that we have superconducting pairing and I cannot straightforwardly diagonalize H. I know how to get the spectrum through BdG formalism but I wouldn't know how to extract the eigenvectors of the associated real-space OBC Hamiltonian. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Might [scicomp.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: I don't think so as "How do I get real space representations of eigenvectors of a system with superconducting pairing?" seems like a very physical question to me.

Comment: Is the problem that you are familiar with diagonalization through a Bogoliubov transformation for small matrices, but not for general $n\times n$ matrices?

Comment: My issue is the overcompleteness of the BdG basis and I don't understand how I could get eigenvectors for the real-space system. I do understand how to extract the spectrum.